# get count of conditionally matched elements from an array in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want comments with today's date and it should be non-empty and how much comments it has via using mongoose. I have tried a lot. Currently, I am trying to achieve with two methods. both have some problems let me explain. please consider I have only two posts in DB one has no comments like: [], and the other has 2 comments two inside it with today date and the 3 is old.

**Method 1 :**

in this method, it returns me today comment but it only returns single comment added on today.
and also returning me another object which has no comments

```
 Post.find({ })
    .select({
      comments: { $elemMatch: { date: { $gt: startOfToday } }  },
      title: 1,
    })
    .exec((err, doc) => {
      if (err) return res.status(400).send(err);

      res.send(doc);
    });
```

**the output of above code is :**

```
[{"_id":"5e9c67f0dd8479634ca255b1","title":"sdasd","comments":[]},{"_id":"5e9d90b4a7008d7bf0c4c96a","title":"sdsd","comments":[{"date":"2020-04-21T04:04:11.058Z","votes":
[{"user":"hhhh","vote":1}],"_id":"5e9e70bbece9c31b33f55041","author":"hhhh","body":"xvxgdggd"}]}]
```

**Method 2 :**
In this method I am using the same thing above inside the found object like this:

```
 Post.find({ comments: { $elemMatch: { date: { $gt: startOfToday } } } })
  .exec((err, doc) => {
    if (err) return res.status(400).send(err);

    res.send(doc);
  });
```

And it returns me first post with all comments (3 comments) but not second post(that is good) that have empty comment array.

**here is the output :**

```
[{"author":{"id":"5e85b42f5e4cb472beedbebb","nickname":"hhhh"},"hidden":false,"_id":"5e9d90b4a7008d7bf0c4c96a","title":"sdsd","body":"dsfdsfdsf","votes":[{"user":"5e85b42f5e4cb472beedbebb","vote":1}],"comments":[{"date":"2020-04-20T12:08:32.585Z","votes":[],"_id":"5e9d90c0a7008d7bf0c4c96b","author":"hhhh","body":"zcxzczxc z zxc"},
{"date":"2020-04-21T04:04:11.058Z","votes":[{"user":"hhhh","vote":1}],"_id":"5e9e70bbece9c31b33f55041","author":"hhhh","body":"xvxgdggd"},
{"date":"2020-04-21T04:56:25.992Z","votes":[],"_id":"5e9e7cf96095882e11dc510c","author":"hhhh","body":"new should appear in feeds"}],"date":"2020-04-20T12:08:20.687Z","createdAt":"2020-04-20T12:08:20.692Z","updatedAt":"2020-04-21T04:56:26.003Z","__v":3}]
```

**This is my post schema :**

```
  const postSchema = new Schema(
  {
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: 1,
      index: true,
    },
    author: {
      id: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User",
      },
      nickname: String,
    },
    body: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    comments: [
      {
        author: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
        body: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
        date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
        votes: [{ user: String, vote: Number, _id: false }],
      },
    ],
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    hidden: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    votes: [{ user: Schema.Types.ObjectId, vote: Number, _id: false }],
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

So, if I have SUM up the things I need today comments and today is 21st April (Two comments) and another comment date is 20. I only need today's comments with its count.

If I forgot something to add please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of changes as [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/index.html#examples) would return only the first matching element from array but not all the matching elements in `comments` array. So it's not useful here, additionally if you want comments for today you need to use `$gte` instead of `$gt` for input `startOfToday`. Finally, You need to use [aggregation-pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) to do this :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   /** Lessen the no.of docs for further stages by filter with condition */
  {
    $match: { "comments.date": { $gte: ISODate("2020-04-21T00:00:00.000Z") } }
  },
  /** Re-create `comments` array by using filter operator with condition to retain only matched elements */
  {
    $addFields: {
      comments: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$comments",
          cond: { $gte: ["$$this.date", ISODate("2020-04-21T00:00:00.000Z")] }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: { count: { $size: "$comments" } } // Add count field which is size of newly created `comments` array(Which has only matched elements)
  }
]);
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_vqCiuB4K4c)